# Google Sheet calculation based on matching cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

How can I compare between A and E and If matches then put the difference in I?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(I4:I), 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I4:I, E4:F, 2, 0))-
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I4:I, A4:B, 2, 0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfectly Working! I was really in need of this. Thank you so much.